# 5 Words with new friends

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, story

I joined my new co-workers at the bar after finally figuring out the menu and ordering myself some beer. I sat down and started chatting and getting to know my new peers.

Gustav told me about how on the weekends he loves to go mountain climbing with his friends and how he loves nature and spending time outside.

Vadim told me about how he loves old-school games, the older the better, and how he thinks video games have to potential to teach skills that can be applied in many fields.

Becky told me about how she loves music and how from a young age she was brought up on the classics and learned to play the piano and the violin. Now she is in the process of starting a punk band with some of her friends to explore the rebellious side of music.

We kept on chatting until we realized that our drinks were empty. Vadim said that as the new guy it was my job to go and get another round. I made my way to the bar and after a few minutes I got the drinks. As I returned to our table, the others were speaking in hushed tones and got quiet as they saw me approach. 
Gustav was the first to speak and said that they wanted to have some fun, so they had a little bar bet for me.
He said that if I get it right they will pay for all my drinks. He then handed me a piece of paper. Becky spoke up and mentioned that I should be able to solve this puzzle if I listened carefully.

```
 Find the 5 hidden words:    

 S U T L W O  
 Z O I R L A   
 J P Z P E D  
 U O P S O M  
 L Y I G I Z  
 S A J O M E
```

After a quick look I couldn't find any words, except maybe "a". If I can't figure this out then I will lose the bet.

**Can you find the 5 hidden words?**

Hint 1:

> This puzzle contains a lot of red herrings. There is no information in the story that is just for flavor. It is either valuable information or used to hide the important parts.

Hint 2:

> It is not a simple word search puzzle. The person who posed this puzzle likes to obfuscate his intent. I wonder who created the puzzle for me?

Hint 3:

> Doing research on each person and their interests might yield results.

Hint 4:

> The five words you need to find will form a sentence. One of the words is not a proper word. Due to certain constraints it had to be abbreviated using text message speak.

Comment: Is this a wordsearch?

Comment: You should mention the rules - which words are valid.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo: Explicit rules would effectively eliminate the "enigmatic puzzle" tag, which I think has been added on purpose.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo: The restriction probably lies in the topics mentioned by the co-workers, so old video games and classic composers are angles from which to attack this. (That's still quite loose, but I have the impression that things become clear once one has a foot in the door, which at the moment I haven't.)

Comment: I am sure it's entirely irrelevant, but just treating the square as an actual wordsearch it contains the words ZIG, DOG, GOD, and OWL as well as the A already mentioned. If I found myself in this actual situation I would be sorely tempted to insist that I have therefore found the required 5 hidden words :-).

Comment: Oh, also ZOS. (A zo, also spelt dzo or zho, is an animal similar to a yak, found in the Himalayas and on Scrabble boards.)

Comment: Hmm. I don't think this is a standard word search. I somehow suspect that there are actually six words of six letters each hidden here: five topical words and one solution. But how? I can see Mozart, which would fit the music theme, but it isn't in any way connected. (But at least there is one letter of Mozart in each column.) Another restriction is that there is no B, C, F, H K, N, Q, V or X and there is only one R and one T, which Mozart would use up. But there are enough vowels to make meaningful words.

Comment: JIGSAW and PUZZLE are in there.. feels right, but does not really help me. Notably this is compatible with Mozart, so going with @MOehm 's theory this would reduce to finding 3 words in 18 letters. Also I have the theory that this is a two-dimensional cryptex

Comment: Hmm, pareidolia. I agree that shoehorning Mozart into a tentative pattern doesn't look too good in hindsight, but you have to start somewhere. The letter distribution isn't close to standard English - too many Zs, too few Es - but there are enough vowels to form words. The grid may be encoded, but there's no key. A quick Caesar rotation with all shifts doesn't yield any sensible words in rows or columns. The grid is 6×6, so maybe the key is to combine adjacent rows and/or columns to get 5 words. (First attempts don't yield anything useful.)

Comment: I could find DOG, GOD, SEA, RIO, LEO, JOT......Dunno if that helps you

Comment: SPOILER: Apparently the creator of the puzzle is male: because he "likes to obfuscate **his** intent"

Comment: I feel like determining who Becky, Gustav and Vadim are will really help in the solution of this puzzle. given the above comment its quite clear what one of the words is. Now we just need 4 more.

Comment: @Brisingr: Given some of the hints, perhaps you only need to determine who one of them are. Maybe the person who created the puzzle for me. I wonder if it is the same person who posed the question to me or if it is someone else.

Comment: Aha. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadim_Gerasimov) seems to be pertinent to the puzzle.

Comment: Good catch @MOehm!

Comment: @MOehm, nicely done. A step in the right direction. Now how can this relate back to the letter grid.

Comment: There's an obvious way but I'm having trouble making it work.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Fischer) could be Gustav, but it might be a stretch

Comment: @DavidFoong Good attempt, but MOehm is already on the right path. As stated in hint1 there are a lot of red herrings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

M Oehm and Gareth McCaughan have already done the hard parts but the answer is

> U wrapped up my game

Which you get by

> Removing the letters which denote tetromino pieces, i.e. {IOTZSJL}

Comment: Congratulations, this seems to be the intended solution! I'm a bit disappointed though, I was in the middle of working out a way to cut the board into tetrominos, rearrange them and form the sentence `A SILLY SUMMER JIGSAW PUZZLE`.

Comment: @Christoph I think that would be at least as good an answer as the real one so you should definitely still do it!

Comment: Haha, if it worked, for sure! But as far as I can tell it's not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Well done! Believe it or not, but I had tried to find a solution similar to Gareth's where I Caesar-shifted all letters according to each teromino. But that ddn't work,of course.

Comment: Nicely Done! You took it the final mile and thus get the spoils of victory. Congrats to M Oehm and Gareth McCaughan for setting the groundwork.

Answer (score 4):

**Certainly-wrong answer**

My purpose in posting this is more to inspire others to do better than because it has any chance of being right. However, I do think this is arguably an acceptable solution to the puzzle originally posed -- but it doesn't match some of what's been said in the hints. And I do suspect that the intended solution is probably along similar lines.

So, based on MOehm's observation that

> Vadim might be Vadim Gerasimov, one of the creators of Tetris,

let us consider the grid of letters to be overlayed on

> a small Tetris game in progress, in which there is one of each kind of piece. (If we ignore differences in rotation and reflection, there are exactly five kinds of Tetris piece, so this is a somewhat plausible thing to do.)

Then they might e.g. be arranged like this:

> `+-------+
>    S | U   T | L   W   O
>      |   +---------------+
>    Z | O | I   R   L   A |
>      |   +---+-----------+
>    J | P | Z | P   E   D |
>      +---+   +---+   +---+
>    U   O   P | S | O | M
>  +-------+---+   +---+
>  | L   Y | I   G | I   Z
>  |       |   +---+
>  | S   A | J | O   M   E
>  +-------+---+`

forming the words

> SLAY (or LAYS)
>  JIGS
>  DOPE (or PEDO)
>  LAIR (or RAIL)
>  POUT

However,

> contrary to the hints none of these has been abbreviated with txt spk, and it's hard to make a plausible sentence out of them. There are plenty of other Tetris-piece-shaped groups of four letters that make words -- and still more if we allow txt-msg abbreviation, which seems like it can make almost *anything* a "word" -- and surely other ways to put five of them together obeying the constraints I've applied above (though of course those constraints are nowhere implied in the puzzle). I haven't spotted any that look very sentence-like, though, and it seems like there are enough possibilities that exhaustive enumeration would be exhausting.

Comment: After reading about Vadim and Tetris, I was like, oh maybe the words are gonna be tetris shaped, and then i was like, well that's going to be really hard not doing that xD

Comment: You are on the right track. Is there any other way to link tetrominos to the letters on the grid?

Comment: I like your logic behind the reason for having 5 words. Unfortunately 5 was just randomly chosen. There is no specific logical reason for it to be 5 words.

Comment: There absolutely is another way to link them, and it's notable (and I would have noted earlier, had I had the brain) that the grid contains an awful lot of letters in {IOTZSJL}. There seem to be quite a lot of possible ways to proceed here...

Comment: ... and, d'oh!, I see that the intended solution (see user39586's answer) is pretty much the opposite of everything I thought of.